# Accounting Management Solution

Tags: php, accounts

Well, my question is about Accounting Management.
I have a system already, it's work fine, but now I need to control the follow intems.

- ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE (My Invoices)
- ACCOUNTS PAYABLE
- SETTLE ACCOUNTS
- CASH FLOW
- GENERAL LEDGER
- FIXED ASSETS
- PAYROLL

On **ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE** I have all my invoice system.
The rest, I need to work on it.

Is this the right way to start a new accounting module?

*Does Anybody have a good source of knowledge about accounts?*

Comment: That's nowhere near enough information to even being to answer your question. You have the other modules - do you mean you wrote those? If so, what makes this one different from the others? Why are you asking about this one in particular?

Comment: Yes, I have the other modules, I wrote all of them. Before we were using another system only to control the accounts of the company, now we need to integrate everything and it includes the accounts. Then I need to build up another module, the problem is not to build up it, but the necessities for this kind of module.
What an accounts module must contain ???

Comment: to be very specific, I need more references on accounts systems. I hope to be clear. Thanks.

Comment: this is related to programming how?

Comment: This might be  fitting on webapps.stackexchange.com but unfortuntately isn't here.

Comment: it is more specific to what the defaults needed to build up an accounting module. As showed on the list I have ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE (My Invoices) and ACCOUNTS PAYABLE, etc.. Is that correct, what is the default to an account system?

Comment: I had already posted it on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/accounting-management-solution
Sorry if it is on the wrong place.

Comment: @Fernando you are in the right place this has nothing to do with using web applications. Try editing your question to make it more specific in terms of what you want achieve... try putting the info in a nice flowchart or the sorts showing your current stack (php, data access, framework etc). As @Saul says just do it and see it works. If it does not you scratch and iterate. In the event that StackOverflow closes it (which has not happened as yet) consider trying http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but not until its closed. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way ... turn.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/go-that-way-really-fast.html)